# Need to send an array in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to send multiples values to a PHP form.
This is the form that I use to send values:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="../WSweb/Factura.php">
    <table width="561" height="79" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td width="30%" height="32">ProductID</td>
            <td width="30%" height="32">SKU</td>
        </tr>
        <?php do { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row_test1['ProductID']; ?>
                    <input
                        type="hidden"
                        name="Product[id][ProductID]"
                        value="<?php echo $row_test1['ProductID']; ?>"
                    />
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $row_test1['SKU']; ?>
                    <input
                        type="hidden"
                        name="Product[id][SKU]"
                        value="<?php echo $row_test1['SKU']; ?>"
                    />
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } while ($row_test1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($test1)); ?>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Update" name="Facturar">
</form>
```

And this is the action file:

```
if(isset($_POST['Update']))
{
    $ProductID=$_POST['Product'];
    print_r(json_encode($ProductID));
}
```

The problem that I have is when I send multiple values, for example the below table:

```
ProductID      SKU
103              WH004BI
137              VO007BI
```

I alway get this result:

```
{"id":{"ProductID":"137","SKU":"VO007BI"}}
```

When I actually want to get a result like this:

```
{"id":[{"ProductID":"103","SKU":"WH004BI"},{"ProductID":"137","SKU":"VO007BI"}]}
```

Comment: Change `name="Product[id][ProductID]"` to `name="Product[id][][ProductID]"`. HTML can have arrays too! This is the same as if you were appending an element to array using the `[]` syntax. Do this for all of the named inputs.

Comment: i just doing but i get this  ProductID SKU 103 WH004BI 137 VO007BI its any form to get this? {"id":[{"ProductID":"103","SKU":"WH004BI"},{"ProductID":"137","SKU":"VO007BI"}]}

Comment: I don't think you can get that structure from a form directly, you'll need to rearrange the data in PHP.

Comment: i exect somenthing like that  {"id":[{"ProductID":"103","SKU":"WH004BI"},{"ProductID":"137","SKU":"VO007BI"}]}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to do something like this:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="../WSweb/Factura.php">
    <table width="561" height="79" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td width="30%" height="32">ProductID</td>
            <td width="30%" height="32">SKU</td>
        </tr>
        <?php $i = 0; ?>
        <?php while ($row_test1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($test1) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row_test1['ProductID']; ?>
                    <input
                        type="hidden"
                        name="Product[id][<?= $i; ?>][ProductID]"
                        value="<?php echo $row_test1['ProductID']; ?>"
                    />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $row_test1['SKU']; ?>
                    <input
                        type="hidden"
                        name="Product[id][<?= $i; ?>][SKU]"
                        value="<?php echo $row_test1['SKU']; ?>"
                    />
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php $i++; ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="Update" name="Facturar">
</form>
```

Note that I have put a `$i = 0` at the start of the loop, and `$i++` at the end of the loop.

Additionally, I have changed the names to the following:

```
name="Product[id][<?= $i; ?>][SKU]"
```

Which will prevent the issue you were having in the comment section regarding an ill-formed array.

Comment: i just doing but i get this result {"id":[{"ProductID":"137","SKU":"VO007BI"]} but i done get all the array

Comment: @JavierJoasimarPalosFlores Please see my code. I have tested this in my own environment and everything appears to be working correctly. Please make sure you copy the code exactly as it is in the answer.